# Comment appelle-t-on un mot qui se décrit lui-même ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Beaucoup de mots ne se décrivent pas, comme par exemple palindrome, qui n'est pas un palindrome, ou adjectif, qui n'est pas un adjectif.

Mais certains mots peuvent être utilisés pour les décrire eux-même. Par exemple, le mot français est français, le mot surrané est surrané, et le mot nom est un nom.

D'autres mots se décrivent à l'opposé, comme le mot long, qui est plutôt court.

Comment appellerait-on ces classes de mots ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S'agirait-il d'un [*autologisme*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autologisme)?

Comment: Effectivement ! Merci, cette page est passionnante !